Question About Limit Points of a Sequence
I have a question regarding the limit points of a sequence:

Suppose we have a sequence $\left(u_{n}\right)$ such that:

The subsequence of even-indexed terms $\left(u_{2n}\right)$ converges to $\ell$.
The subsequence of odd-indexed terms $\left(u_{2n + 1}\right)$ converges to $\ell^{\prime}$.


My question is:

Can we conclude that the only limit points ( or accumulation points ) of the sequence $\left(u_n\right)$ are $\ell$ and $\ell^{\prime}$ ?.



I would appreciate any clarification or a rigorous explanation of this result.
Thank you in advance for your help !.

Yes indeed. What definition do you use for limit points? And what have you tried? For n big enough every term of upyour sequence should be lying in the neighbourhoods of l and l’ can you show that?

@ julio_es_sui_glace. The statement is true indeed. A rigorous proof would be nice.

Felix Marin, if you see this, can you comment on why you changed two of the sentences to a fixed-width font (like this)? Does that mean something? Just curious!

By contradiction, assume that a subsequence $(u_{n_{k}})$ converges to $c\notin \{\ell,\ell^{\prime}\}$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Losing no generailty, we may assume that $\ell< \ell^{\prime}$ (one can reiterate the proof below when $\ell> \ell^{\prime}$ with minor changes).
Case 1:  Assume that $\ell<c< \ell^{\prime}$.
Then, for every $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}\min\{c-\ell,\ell^{\prime}-c\}$, there exists an integer $N$ such that
$$c-\epsilon<u_{n_{k}}<c+\epsilon,\qquad (1)$$
$$\ell-\epsilon<u_{2k}<\ell+\epsilon,$$
for all $k\geq N$. Notice that $(1)$ is satisfied, in particular, by all the terms of
order $n_{k}$ that is even and larger than $N$.
This leads to the contradiction
$$(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)\cap (\ell-\epsilon,\ell+\epsilon)\neq\emptyset \Longrightarrow\ell+\epsilon>c-\epsilon.$$
Now, you complete the cases
Case 2:   $c<\ell$.
Case 3:   $c>\ell^{\prime}$.

Here's what I believe is the simplest argument.
Any subsequence of $\{u_{n_i}\}$ of $\{u_n\}$ will either have

a finite number of the even terms, and an infinite number of the odd terms
a finite number of the odd terms, and an infinite number of the even terms
an infinite number of even and an infinite number of odd terms.

If there is a finite number of even terms there is a natural number $N$ where for all $m> N$,  $n_m$ is odd.  And in that case the limit  must be the same as the limit  of the sequence odd terms, that is, $l'$
Same argument if there are a finite number of odd terms the limit must be the sequence of even terms, namely $l$.
If there are infinite number of even and odds there will be infinite subsequences of the even terms converging to $l$ and infinite subsequences of odd terms converging to $l'$ and (assuming $l \ne l'$) there are no limit of the sequence.
.....
The above argument assumes you are familiar with the results. If a sequence converges to a point then any subsequence converges to the same point ii) if a sequence converges to a point the a sequence that has at most a finite number of terms not in the sequence must converge to the same point.

It is not true. If your sequence is $l', l, l', l, \ldots$, then
$$
\{u_n : n \ge 1 \} = \{l, l'\},
$$
which has no limit points (if the underlying space is $\mathbb{R}$, for example).

The limit point of a sequence is not the same thing as a limit point of the set of the terms of the sequence. The limit point of a sequence means any neighborhood of the point will contain infinite numbers of the sequence.  These terms do NOT need to be distinct.  The just need to have distinct indexes.  As $u_2=u_4=u_6=..... = l$ any neighborhood of $l$ will contain an infinite number $u_{2n}$ terms.  Yes, they are all the same number, $l$, but that doesn't matter... they are different terms in the sequence.

I think it's a matter of convention. In some books, a limit point of a sequence is defined as a limit point of the set of the terms of the sequence.

@Inhyeok Baek. But the sequence in the question is not of the structure you are discussing.
